Next.js update client component on successful login
I am making a Next.js + DRF website with authentication. In my navbar I want to render either "log in" or "log out" button. So I pass a boolean prop from server side to client-side page:
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {

  const session = await auth();

  return (
    ...
      <NavBar authenticated={!!session} />
    ...
  );
}

export default function NavBar({ authenticated }: { authenticated: boolean }) {
  
  return (
    ...
          {authenticated ? (
            <form action={logOut}>
              <button>
                Sign out
              </button>
            </form>
          ) : (
            <Link
              href="/login"              
            >
              Sign in
            </Link>
          )}
    ...
  );
}

export default function LoginPage() {
  const [errorMessage, dispatch] = useFormState(authenticate, undefined);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  if (errorMessage === "ok") {
    router.push("/");
  }

  return (
    <LoginForm />
  );
}


But the problem is that after successful login, navbar doesn't get reloaded, so it stays "Sign in". What is the correct approach to handle authentication state on client side?
Fixed the issue by  replacing router.push("/") after singUp is executed with window.location.href = ("/").

Can you describe your fix a little further? Did you mean to say "after signUp" is executed or "after signIn" is executed? And where did you put window.location.href = ("/")?

I have authenticate that executes signIn and returns errorMessage after which I initially used router.push("/"), but then replaced it with window.location.href = ("/") which also reloads the page completely.

To handle this, you can use the SessionProvider from next-auth/react and the useSession hook to manage the session state on the client side. This approach ensures that the session state is always up-to-date in your components.

I am using App Router, I don't think SessionProvider works with it.
